# docker swarm init on windows container output nothing

Tags: docker, containers, init, swarm

I create docker swarm use command:"docker swarm init ",but there is nothing output.

```
PS C:\ConsoleZ> docker swarm init
```

then I use command "docker node ls" in another termination , it output :

```
PS C:\ConsoleZ> docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME  STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
rttn874z4rpnuisrcse6869zu *            Down    Active        Leader

PS C:\ConsoleZ> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
w5d6snuid9pi        ingress             overlay             swarm
8bc0801a3b5a        nat                 nat                 local
285a0eacfb3f        none                null                local
```

the manager node why is DOWN and no HOSTNAME?

And I reboot my computer, the swarm I create is lost, I must use the init command create another one.

Is somebody know why?

by the way , I use windows container with windows server 2016

```
PS C:\ConsoleZ> docker info
Containers: 1
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 1
Images: 3
Server Version: 17.03.1-ee-3
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
Swarm: pending
  NodeID: rttn874z4rpnuisrcse6869zu
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: 9bie63os8jzg0e8vvfx3lg3or
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
Node Address: 192.168.1.219
Manager Addresses:
  0.0.0.0:2377
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.1198.amd64fre.rs1_release_sec.170427-1353)
Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 1.999 GiB 
Name: windock219
ID: 7AOY:OT6V:BTJV:NCHA:3OF5:5WR5:K2YR:CFG3:VXLD:QTMD:GA3D:ZFJ2
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 192.168.1.245
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```